# Elasticsearch Error - Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [RED] (reason: [shards failed

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I am using `elasticdump` to dump a huge dataset into an elasticsearch node with the command : `elasticdump --input=./xyz.json --output=http://localhost:9200/` . Everything goes normal but after some time I see these error messages in the console:

```
_type: 'doc',
_id: 'lzHMQmUBQ1VCv6VBROQA',
status: 503,
error:
{ type: 'unavailable_shards_exception',
 reason: '[logstash-2018.08.16][2] primary shard is not active Timeout: 
[1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[logstash-2018.08.16][2]] containing [31] requests]' } }
```

On inspection of the elasticsearch logs, the following errors are visible :

```
[2018-08-31T11:27:21,496][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [dqSwClD] Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [RED] (reason: [shards failed [[logstash-2018.08.16][2]] ...]).
```

I am not sure what has caused the `shard failure` and several troubleshooting efforts have proved abortive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can find at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html, there are plenty tips to optimize bulk indexing:

- Disable replica
- Disable almost realtime refresh  (`refresh_interval` of the index)
- etc...

Comment: thank you for your response. I looked up the link you provided, it has a lot of information, however I am not sure where to effect those configurations. I don't think it should be in the `elasticsearch.yml` file since those settings are  e.g. `replica` are not part of the options in the file. Do I have to execute the settings as stated here [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-disk-usage.html] i.e. against the `elasticsearch` endpoint ? Maybe you can provide an example.

Comment: (Disable replica) is setting index.number_of_replicas of an index to 0 which you can do dynamically (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html). Even you can perform refresh_interval the same way.